# How to prevent URL encode when opening local URL with google-chrome command?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, command-line, urldecode

For example, when I type the following:

```
google-chrome https://somewebsite.com/somepage/#someheading
```

It will open the exact URL (without encode) in the browser.

But when I try to open from local file:

```
google-chrome ~/localdirectory/index.html#someheading
```

It will open the following:

```
file:///home/imampt/localdirectory/index.html%23someheading
```

Which will result in "Your file was not found".

The following command works, however:

```
google-chrome ~/localdirectory/index.html
```

How to open a local URL without encoding from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow appending `file://` as prefix to the URL solve the issue for me:

```
google-chrome file://$HOME/localdirectory/index.html#someheading
```